# How to copy an input form to a newly created workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I realize it was not clear due to copying a part of the macro. Below macro, which starts with the new WB, gives an error 424 object required. checking in manual mode the ProjectWB and SourceWB are loaded correctly.

```
Sub Copy_Form_to_new_WB()
   ProjectWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
   SourceWB = "Interpretation Analysis 2.0.xlsm"
   SourceWB.VBProject.VBComponents("Input_Analysis_Form").Export_ 
       "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
   ProjectWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
   Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
   Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frx"
End Sub
```

In the case, I dim both ProjectWB and SourceWB I get the error Compile error: invalid qualifier. and the ProjectWB in line 8 is highlighted

```
Sub Copy_Form_to_new_WB()
  Dim SourceWB As Integer
  Dim ProjectWB As Integer
  ProjectWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  SourceWB = "Interpretation Analysis 2.0.xlsm"
  SourceWB.VBProject.VBComponents("Input_Analysis_Form").Export_ 
     "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
  ProjectWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
 Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
 Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frx"
End Sub
```

What is going wrong?

---

**Original question:**

In a macro, I'm creating a new workbook which works ok. Now I want to copy an input form from the existing workbook to the new. Checking the Internet I found some bits and parts. To be clear I've copied two parts of the macro.

```
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim ProjectWB As Workbook
SourceWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'now the part to create the new workbook when this is active
ProjectWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
SourceWB.VBProject.VBComponents("Input_Analysis_Form").Export_ 
"Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
DestinationWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frx"
```

Now I get run time error 91 "object variable or with block not set"
what would be the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version of your code, you are declaring (by not explicitly declaring them) both `ProjectWB` and `SourceWB` as `Variant/String`, but then attempting to use them as `Workbook` objects.

In the second version of your code, you're explicitly declaring both `ProjectWB` and `SourceWB` as `Integer`, but then trying to assign `String` values to them before attempting to use them as `Workbook` objects.

Based on your revised code samples, I believe you are trying to do:

```
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim ProjectWB As Workbook
'This line is the only difference to my previous answer
Set SourceWB = Workbooks("Interpretation Analysis 2.0.xlsm")
Set ProjectWB = ActiveWorkbook
'Actually, here's a second difference - I hadn't noticed the missing space before
' the line continuation character earlier
SourceWB.VBProject.VBComponents("Input_Analysis_Form").Export _ 
"Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
DestinationWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frx"
```

---

**Original answer:**

You have declared `SourceWB` and `ProjectWB` as `Workbook` objects, but then just assign a `String` to them (the name of some workbooks).

```
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim ProjectWB As Workbook
Set SourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
'now the part to create the new workbook when this is active
'This doesn't make sense, because it will be the same as "SourceWB"
Set ProjectWB = ActiveWorkbook
SourceWB.VBProject.VBComponents("Input_Analysis_Form").Export_ 
"Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
DestinationWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frx"
```

Comment: I've put in a follow-up question after your advice. Please check above

Comment: @CoertvanDuijnen - I was about to say that your edit to the question didn't work, but then realised you had posted an "answer" rather than updating your question.  Please delete that answer before the moderators have to.  Meanwhile I will edit your question for you, and amend my answer to reflect your new issues.

Answer (score 0):

I realize it was not clear due to copying a part of the macro.
Below macro, which starts with the new WB, gives an error 424 object required.
checking in manual mode the ProjectWB and SourceWB are loaded correctly.

```
Sub Copy_Form_to_new_WB()
   ProjectWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
   SourceWB = "Interpretation Analysis 2.0.xlsm"
   SourceWB.VBProject.VBComponents("Input_Analysis_Form").Export_ 
       "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
   ProjectWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
   Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
   Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frx"
End Sub
```

In the case, I dim both ProjectWB and SourceWB I get the error Compile error: invalid qualifier. and the ProjectWB in line 8 is highlighted

```
Sub Copy_Form_to_new_WB()
  Dim SourceWB As Integer
  Dim ProjectWB As Integer
  ProjectWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  SourceWB = "Interpretation Analysis 2.0.xlsm"
  SourceWB.VBProject.VBComponents("Input_Analysis_Form").Export_ 
     "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
  ProjectWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
 Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frm"
 Kill "Input_Analysis_Form.frx"
End Sub
```

What is going wrong?